# How to get only displayable screen on react-native android

Tags: android, react-native

I know in react-native, to avoid status bar, ios have someething like `SafeAreaView`, but in android, i get block by bottom navigation like this

[image]

So my question is how to avoid the bottom navigation on android in react-native, thank you a lots

Here is the style of bottom bar :

```
const SELECTED_ROW_CONTAINER: ViewStyle = {
  // position: "absolute",

  width: widthScreen,
  height: onePercentHeight * 10,
  position: "absolute",
  bottom: 0,
  paddingHorizontal: spacingWidth[6],
  paddingBottom: spacingHeight[2],
  // alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "space-between",
  alignItems: "center",
  backgroundColor: color.white,
};
```

Comment: can u please share the styling of bottom navigation

Comment: I just update the question @chikabala

Comment: please try this styling instead `backgroundColor:'white', alignSelf: 'center', position: 'absolute',   bottom: 0, height:50, justifyContent:'center'`

Comment: i tried but no luck

Answer (score -1):

in Scrollview make like this

`android:layout_height="0dp"`

example :

```
  <ScrollView
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dash_bottomNavigation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp">
        </ScrollView>
```

and don't forget  use NestedScrollView if you have Recyclerview

Comment: I use react native, but how can i do that?

Comment: with what you wrap your component? are you need scrollview? or safeareaview?

Comment: what ScrollView has to do with the problem??

Comment: I still dont understand how to do this with react-native @@

Comment: the problem is only in bottom navigation styling, consider uploading your code into a  snack

Comment: i already got this case, the problem is you wrap it with view. better u change and wrap with scrollview and change the layout height

Comment: @DickaReynaldi what if he's using a ScrollView in the screen this gonne create another problem which is nested virtualisation, and note that the component will be scrollable so not the wanted result at all